# Is it possible to perform this query with Laravel or Sql with my database structure?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a database with a table `articles` and a table `category`.

My table `articles` have some fields. And one that is `category_id` and a another `orientation`.

Categories, in my design, are arranged by orientation. Here is an example
[image]

So, I would like to get all category BUT these categories must belong to the right orientation. **I want list of all category who have articles with 'web' orientation**, by example.

I do not know if it's possible with this architecture and if you understand me.

Any help is welcome

UPDATE : adding the schemas

[image]

Comment: Since you didn't share you table schemas, there isn't a way to tell if it's possible. Please edit your question and add the schemas

Comment: @SloanThrasher I add the schemas, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have your models and relations set up, I believe this should do what you want:

```
$categories = Category::whereHas('articles', function($query) {
   $query->where('orientation', 'web')
})->get()
```

From the Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations):

> If you need even more power, you may use the `whereHas` and `orWhereHas`
>   methods to put "where" conditions on your has queries. These methods
>   allow you to add customized constraints to a relationship constraint,
>   such as checking the content of a comment

Comment: Oh yes! THANK YOU VERY MUCH ! I've been searching for hours